# Can't upgrade Deployment from apiVersion extensions/v1beta1 to apps/v1, it uses extensions/v1beta1 automatically

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

I currently have a GKE Kubernetes 1.15 cluster and I'm planning to upgrade to 1.16. Since 1.16 doesn't support certain APIs I have to change my deployments from extensions/v1beta1 to apps/v1.

Using this simple deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

When I apply it into my 1.15 cluster: `kubectl -n mynamespace deployment.yml`, what is actually see is the following (`kubectl -n mynamespace get deployments nginx-deployment`):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
...
```

As you can see the actual apiVersion is extensions/v1beta1 instead of apps/v1. Why isn't it applying the version I specified?

**UPDATE:**

This is my kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T23:41:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.14", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.9-gke.24", GitCommit:"39e41a8d6b7221b901a95d3af358dea6994b4a40", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-29T01:24:35Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: How old is your kubectl? That's what determines which version it asks for.

Comment: I have an up-to-date version: `brew upgrade kubernetes-cli` ->  `kubernetes-cli 1.17.4 already installed`

Comment: Check with `kubectl version`. Sometimes people end up with an old version from google stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apiVersion returned from `kubectl get` won't necessarily match up with the actual apiVersion of your current configuration.

See here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62283#issuecomment-380968868

Quote:

> `kubectl get` uses server-preferred order, which will prefer the `extensions` API group for backward compatibility, until `extensions` is removed. That is to say, `kubectl get deployment` uses extenions/v1beta1 endpoint by default.
>
> To get deployments under `apps` API group, you can use `kubectl get deployment.apps`, which returns you `apps/v1` deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily kubectl, the CLI swiss knife has a tool to help with this conversion. If you have any old manifests that are throwing this error, add `kubectl convert` into the pipeline and it should work properly with Kubernetes 1.16.

Please take a look here: [apiversions-update](https://medium.com/star-systems-labs/kubectl-convert-update-api-versions-automatically-e669add17e3d).

`kubectl convert` command has changed the API versions to be compatible for k8s 1.16. You just need to make sure that you use a recent version of kubectl to have the `convert` option built into it.

Comment: Upvoted for usefulness.   Doesn't help the OP or me because we've already converted the deployment manually, but is a useful related tool I wish I knew about before.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

**Install kubetcl convert via the link below:**

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/

**The command below will convert your deployment.yaml (of apiversion: extensions/v1beta1 to apps/v1), and write it to a new file deploy.yaml**

```
kubectl convert -f deployment.yaml --local -o yaml > deploy.yaml
```